# How can I identify columns when SELECTing from multiple tables with JDBC?

Tags: sql, jdbc, join, resultset, javadb

I have two tables that I join on the id-column, they look like:

```
+-------+
| users |
+----+--+---+
| id | name |
+----+------+

+-------+
| posts |
+-------+------+---------+
| id | user_id | message |
+----+---------+---------+
```

And now I want to select all posts and include the username, with:

```
SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE user_id = users.id
```

And then I try to get the values with:

```
ResultSet rs = // SQL
if(rs.next()) {
    rs.getInt("posts.id");
    ...
}
```

But I get `SQLException` when executing `rs.getInt("posts.id")` :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'posts.id' not found.
```

**How can I get the values from the SQL-query above using JDBC, and JavaDB/Derby as database?**

How can I distinguish between the `id` column in the `users` and `posts` table when retrieving values with `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're attempting to retrieve the `id` value, but you're using "posts.id" to reference it.  ***Don't***

All you need is the column name or alias, not the table name as well:

```
ResultSet rs = // SQL
if(rs.next()) {
  rs.getInt("id");
  ...
}
```

It would've worked if your column name itself was "posts.id", but I recommend using underscore (_) instead of a period should you choose to update the table.

### But I have an id column in both tables, how do i distinguish between them?

---

You need to specify a column alias:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id,
       p.name,
       u.id AS users_id, 
       p.user_id, --redundant due to relationship, omit if possible
       u.message
  FROM POSTS p
  JOIN USERS u ON u.id = p.user_id
```

...and reference that column alias in the Java code:

```
ResultSet rs = // SQL
if(rs.next()) {
  rs.getInt("post_id");
  ...
}
```

Comment: But I have an `id` column in both tables, how do i distinguish between them if I use only `rs.getInt("id")` instead of `rs.getInt("posts.id")` and `rs.getInt("users.id")` ?

Comment: I was able to use the table name dot column name syntax without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 : use alias

```
select u.id as uid, u.name, p.id as post_id, p.user_id, p.message from
users u inner join posts p on u.id=p.user_id
```

Solution 2: remove the duplicate user.id since you already have it in the posts table

```
select p.user_id, u.name, p.id as post_id, p.message from
users u inner join posts p on u.id=p.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias the column names

```
SELECT
    posts.id posts_id,
    name name,
    id id,
    user_id,
    message
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users 
    ON posts.user_id = users.id
```

depending on your sql flavour, that alias may need to be

```
posts.id as posts_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### How can I get the values from the SQL-query above using JDBC, and JavaDB/Derby as database?

To get values, you should use the `ResultSet`'s column name. The column name used in the `ResultSet` will be original column name or the alias.

If your `ResultSet` has columns with the same name or alias, the `getInt()` will return the first match.

With your select ...

```
SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE user_id = users.id
```

...the `rs.getInt()` will return only the `posts.id` since it will the first column.

> ### How can I distinguish between the id column in the users and posts table when retrieving values with ResultSet?

You can use a unique alias for every column or you can use the `ResultSetMetaData`

---

- ***Solution 1:*** Use SQL alias

SQL

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id,
    p.name AS post_name,
    u.id AS user_id, 
    u.message AS user_message
  FROM POSTS p
  JOIN USERS u
    ON u.id = p.user_id
```

Java

```
ResultSet rs = // SQL
if(rs.next()) {
  rs.getInt("post_id");
  rs.getInt("user_id");
}
```

---

- ***Solution 2:*** Use `ResultSetMetaData`

SQL

```
SELECT p.id
    p.name
    u.id
    u.message
  FROM POSTS p
  JOIN USERS u
    ON u.id = p.user_id
```

Java

```
Integer userID;
Integer postID;

ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
if (rs.next()) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= rsMeta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    String table = rsMeta.getTableName(i);
    String col = rsMeta.getColumnName(i);

    if(table.equals("users") && col.equals("id")){
      userID = rs.getInt(i);
      continue;
    }

    if(table.equals("posts") && col.equals("id")) {
      userID = rs.getInt(i);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can simplify these further by getting data as per the column index instead of getting it by column name..!! what ever data we retrieve from DB is stored in result set in the column order as per the select statement so instead of getting data as per the column name prefer fetching data as per the column index in result set..

ex:

```
String query = " select age,num from table_abc";
ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next){
   int var1= rs.getInt(1);
   int var2= rs.getInt(2);
}
```

these will help you do away with complexity and confusion created due to similar column names in your database tables..

Hope these helps...

All the best..!!